# identify duplicate data in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to find animals that have same ident but different key i.e  same "alt_anim_ident" but different "animals_key"

[image: Animals Table]

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's language for stored procedures. And PL/SQL Developer is an Oracle only tool. But pgAdmin is a Postgres tool. Which database are you _really_ using?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT yt1.* , yt2.* /*SELECT both data, you can put * if you want too */
FROM yourtable yt1   
INNER JOIN yourtable yt2 /*Do self-checking*/
ON yt1.alt_anim_ident = yt2.alt_anim_ident /*Check those with the same alt_anim_ident*/
WHERE yt11.animals_key <> yt2.animals_key; /*Eliminates data which pointing to itself*/
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: I have tried this code and it answered my question but causing the data to display twice

Comment: @TechPathi, twice in terms of columns or rows?

Comment: @Vic Lee - I apologies, i take back what i said. I re-ran the query and it worked without any duplication. J

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM thetable t                                   -- How to find animals
WHERE EXISTS (                                    -- where (different animals) exist
        SELECT * FROM thetable x 
        WHERE x.alt_anim_ident = t.alt_anim_ident -- that have same ident
        AND x.animals_key <> t.animals_key        -- but different key
        )
ORDER BY t.alt_anim_ident, t.animals_key
        ;
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Comment: Consider it done. Now please do a similar comment on Vic Lee's answer, which lists all m*(m-1) pairs within every group of m having the same `ident`.